# Vagrant Commands Different Folders

Tags: bash, shell, virtualization, vagrant

In Bashes/Shells it is usually pretty easy to perform commands in one folder but have it apply to another folder. For example, with `ls` you can do `ls -l /some/folder` or `ls /some/folder -l`, and both list all files/directories in the `/some/folder` directory as well as permissions, owners, etc.

Is there any way to do this with the command-line VM managing program Vagrant? When I tried, from the C: directory (`/c`) with Git Bash (msysgit), `vagrant init some/vagrant/folder`, the created files & folders still got put in the folder I was in, `/c`, instead of the folder I specified, `/c/some/vagrant/folder`, and when I did `vagrant some/vagrant/folder init`, it threw an error.

Is there any way to have `vagrant` commands apply to a folder you're not in, or do I just have to `cd` every time I want to initialize a VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/init.html) says that `vagrant init` intializes the current directory. So vagrant itself won't allow what you want. However, bash can help:

```
(cd some/vagrant/folder; vagrant init)
```

What this does is start a subshell in which you first immediately change directory and then issue the `vagrant init` command. Running it in a subshell prevents the `cd` from messing up the current working directory of your interactive session.

Comment: @Louie, thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! It's not even that much more typing than my original command! +100

Comment: Would the PATH variable help in this?

Comment: Or some other environment variable?

Comment: I'm not seeing setting an environment variable being useful in this case.

Comment: Idk, just asking. Your original answer was great, just wondering if there is a better way is all. Also, sorry I called you @Louie before, I meant Louis.